# Is it possible to get all entries of a Mapping or Array?

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle

For debugging a smart contract, it would be helpful to see all entries of an Array or Mapping object in the smart contract.

When using Truffle, I can see individual elements of a public array with valid index *i* by running `mycontract.myarray(i)` but running `mycontract.myarray()` yields a `BigNumber Error`.

[This question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-the-full-state-of-a-contract) indicated that getting the full readout is not straightforward because the getter functions for mappings and arrays expect index keys. However, has anyone found a way to do this in geth or Truffle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The abi is limited to a finite number (16, or 8 for strings) of values. See over here for some organizational patterns [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity).

You want the client side to do the iterating over the list so the cost per call remains constant.

Hope it helps.