# How can I view all the values of all the variables in a smart contract when using ganache-cli and web3.py?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, web3.py, ganache-cli

I'm new to this domain and have used remix since few months. Now I'm developing application locally. I do not want to write getters for every variable just to know my previous transactions worked correctly.
Is there any way we can see value of every variable at once? I think this kind of feature helps speed up the development in local environment.

Answer (score 0):

For public variables getters are generated automatically at compile time, e.g. if you declare `someVar` public, you will be able to call `someVar()` to get the value of `someVar`.

You can also dump public vars in your tests. Here's how I would begin to tackle the issue using ABI (ABIs are saved in `artifacts/contracts/ContractName.sol/ContractName.json`) files. Here's a sample test file:

````
...

// @ts-ignore
import ContractNameABI from '../artifacts/contracts/ContractName.sol/ContractName.json';```

async function dumpPublicVars(ABIitem, contract) {
    if (ABIitem.inputs.length == 0 &&
        ABIitem.stateMutability == "view" &&
        ABIitem.type == "function") {
        console.log("ABIitem.name(): ", ABIitem.name);
        console.log(await contract[ABIitem.name.toString() + "()"]());
    }
}

describe("NFTContract", function () {

    async function deployContractFixture() {
        
        const [
            owner, minter, entity
        ] = await ethers.getSigners();

        const NFTContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("NFTContract", "NFTC", owner);
        const nftcontract = await NFTContract.deploy();

        const nftcontractabi = ContractNameABI.abi;
        
        return {
            nftcontract, minter, entity, nftcontractabi
        };
    }
    
    describe("ERC721", function () {

        it("mintTo()", async function () {
            const {
                contract, minter, entity, contractabi
            } = await loadFixture(deployContractFixture);

            contractabi.forEach(item => dumpPublicVars(item, contract));

            await contract.mintTo(minter.address); // 1 // called by owner
            await contract.connect(minter).mintTo(minter.address); // 1 // called by another account (minter)
            await contract.connect(entity).mintTo(minter.address); // 1 // called by another account (entity)
        });
    });
});
````

Comment: Would you like to suggest some automated way of viewing them?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself. but here's an interesting conversation: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-the-full-state-of-a-contract

Comment: See my updated answer. It goes through the ABI and logs public vars values. Feel free to adapt it to your needs. Hope that helps.